# Why chromium browser return outerWidth as 0 when links are opened in new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, chromium

test.html

```
<a href="test2.html">Click</a>
```

test2.html

```
<script>
    alert(window.outerWidth);
</script>
```

Left clicking the link return correct value

Opening the link with middle mouse button returns 0 (opening link in new tab, same thing happen when you one link in new tab through right click option)

This issue does not exist in Firefox

Comment: It could be that tabs which do not have focus does not have width?